# SQL Nested Query Homework SQL Fiddle

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

Find Insurance Company with the maximal number of members (patients).

Thats the Database and my first attempt to get closer :

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4b2ed/27

```
SELECT  P.cid AS cid, COUNT ( P.pid ) AS CountP
FROM        Patient P
GROUP BY    P.cid
```

how do i get the max countp?

Comment: Just FYI, your question says MySQL but your fiddle is for MSSQL.

Comment: its a bug in fiddle i ran it on mysql im sure...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just order your results in descending numbers of patients, and take only the first record.

```
SELECT  P.cid AS cid, COUNT( P.pid ) AS CountP
FROM        Patient P
GROUP BY    P.cid
ORDER BY    CountP DESC
LIMIT 1
```

If more than one insurance company might have that maximal number of members and you want to fetch all of them, you will need to use a subquery:

```
SELECT  P.cid AS cid, COUNT( P.pid ) AS CountP
FROM        Patient P
GROUP BY    P.cid
HAVING      CountP = (
    SELECT   COUNT(pid) AS c
    FROM     Patient
    GROUP BY cid
    ORDER BY c DESC
    LIMIT 1
);
```

In the strange situation you describe in your comments, where one is unable to use `LIMIT`, you could do:

```
SELECT  P.cid AS cid, COUNT( P.pid ) AS CountP
FROM        Patient P
GROUP BY    P.cid
HAVING      CountP = (SELECT MAX(d.c) FROM (
    SELECT   COUNT(pid) AS c
    FROM     Patient
    GROUP BY cid
) AS d);
```

Comment: @OfekRon: As Joachim mentioned above, your sqlfiddle is configured for MSSQL, whereas your question is tagged (and my answer is for) MySQL.  I have create [an equivalent MySQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c4a9f/2) showing the above query working.  For MSSQL, you'll need to use `TOP(1)` in place of `LIMIT 1` (which I believe needs to be placed immediately after the `SELECT` keyword).

Comment: @eggyal you are right, tho Im not supposed to use Limit, is there another way by nested query?

Comment: You don't even **need** the `LIMIT` in my query - you could return all the records and only inspect the first record in the result set.

Comment: @OfekRon: See the update to my answer, above - whilst this uses a subquery, it still uses `LIMIT`; is that what you were after, or is `LIMIT` **completely** verboten?

Comment: what if you were not allowed to use limit? could u do it with max? or nested query? we didnt learn about Limit keyword so we are not suppose to use it (yet)

Comment: It can be done using another subquery and `MAX`, yes.  Why don't you have a go yourself?

Comment: ive been trying to do so for 3 hours getting errors all over the place :O

Comment: SELECT  P.cid AS cid, COUNT( P.pid ) AS CountP
FROM        Patient P
GROUP BY    P.cid
HAVING      CountP = (
        SELECT MAX (d.c) 
        FROM     (SELECT   COUNT(pid) AS c
                  FROM     Patient
                  GROUP BY cid ) AS d
);

Comment: @OfekRon: See above for one possible solution; although, frankly, in your position I'd argue with my professor in defence of my earlier solutions.  **EDIT**: Ah, looks like you got there at about the same time as me!  Well done.

Comment: I was close, tho i didnt really manged to make it work as you did :(

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following:
    max(count(P.pid))

Comment: I believe @eggyal has nailed it

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  P.cid, COUNT ( P.pid ) AS CountP
FROM    Patient P
GROUP BY    P.cid
compute max(count(p.pid))
```

Comment: im not supposed to use the keyword compute (and it doesnt work on sqlfiddle btw)

Answer (score 0):

Wow - lots of constraints.  Here you go:

```
SELECT MAX(CountP) FROM (
  SELECT P.cid, COUNT ( P.pid ) AS CountP
  FROM  Patient P
  GROUP BY  P.cid
) winner
```